# Xamarin: Cancel HttpClient request before timeout is completed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I wish to cancel the HttpClient request while running Asynchronous Task before the timeout of 90 seconds as specified in my code:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

public async Task<string> GetData()
{
  try
  {
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    cookies.SetCookies(uri, strCookie);
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 90);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,cts.Token);
    res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return res;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
}

public void CancelTask()
{
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

At certain point of time when `GetData()` method is executing I am calling `CancelTask()` method to cancel the request immediately, it continues till the timeout of 90 seconds.
Is it possible to cancel the task before the timeout value is reached. I am doing this in order to solve a particular scenario in my App.

Comment: Reviewing the source code here should prove useful. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L394

Comment: @Nkosi: I am trying to cancel in between when the Task is executing before the timeout, can you plz figure out the clue in the source you provide, I found there as it is checking before the asyn task method is about to be executing not in running state.

Comment: That would be dependent on the `HttpMessageHandler` implementation, which is what would be doing the actual sending. In this case that is usually defaulted to `HttpClientHandler`

Comment: I'd be helpful to see the code where you invoke `GetData()` and `CancelTask()`. Sounds like your `CancelTask()` blocked by the execution of `GetData()`.